# Read several files, and stack them into a single multilevel data frame. Each file has the same column names

Tags: python, database, pandas

I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to use the multilevel index to stack several data frames into a single one instead of a list of data frames like the one I am doing. Thanks

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

glist=glob.glob("./path/*.csv")

D=[]
for file in glist:
    X=pd.read_csv(file,names=['name1','name2','name3'],index_col = 0, header=0)
    D.append(X)
```

Comment: It is my first time posting a question, so I don't know how to submit text correctly. But I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to use the multilevel index to stack several dataframes into a single one instead of a list of dataframes like the one I am doing. Thanks

Comment: you need `pd.concat(D,axis=0,keys=['name1','name2','name3'])`

Answer (score 0):

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893509/how-to-read-multiple-files-and-merge-them-into-a-single-pandas-data-frame) for a good start, you need to put the paths in a list, than use pandas `concat()` to put them together

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from os import path
dfs = [pd.read_csv(path.join('data',x)) for x in os.listdir("data") if path.isfile(path.join("data",x))]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

If you like to assign new columns to a data frame use [assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
two join multiple dataframes based on multiple levels of index look
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937433/efficiently-joining-two-dataframes-based-on-multiple-levels-of-a-multiindex)

and in order to combine two dataframes into one with hierachial column index, do something like:

```
 pd.concat(dict(df1 = df1, df2 = df2),axis=1)
```

also Pandas has a built in function to merge two data frames, look [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what I wanted. Thank you Wen.

```
       D=pd.DataFrame()
       for file in glist:
               X=pd.read_csv(file,names=['name1','name2','name3'],header=0,index_col=0)
               D=pd.concat([X,D],axis=0)
```